# How to plot from multiple datasets with same fieldnames?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a few monthly datasets of usage stats stored in different CSVs, with a couple hundred fields. I am cutting off the top 30 of each one, but the bottom will change (and the top as changes as stuff is banned, albeit less commonly). Currently I have the lines representing months, but I want the points to be (y=usage %) and (x=month) with the legend being different users.

```
column[0] is their number in the file (1-30)
column[1] is their name
column[2] is the usage percent
```

```py
AprilStats = pd.read_csv(r'filepath', nrows=30)
MayStats = pd.read_csv(r'filepath', nrows=30)
JuneStats = pd.read_csv(r'filepath', nrows=30)

## Assign labels and sources

labels = [[AprilStats.columns[1]], [MayStats.columns[1]], [JuneStats.columns[1]]]
AprilUsage=np.array(AprilStats[AprilStats.columns[2]].tolist())
MayUsage=np.array(MayStats[MayStats.columns[2]].tolist())
JuneUsage=np.array(JuneStats[JuneStats.columns[2]].tolist())

x = np.array(AprilStats[AprilStats.columns[0]].tolist())
y = np.array(AprilStats[AprilStats.columns[2]].tolist())
my_xticks = AprilStats[AprilStats.columns[1]].tolist()
plt.xticks(x, my_xticks, rotation='55')

x1 = np.array(MayStats[MayStats.columns[0]].tolist())
y1 = np.array(MayStats[MayStats.columns[2]].tolist())
my_xticks1 = MayStats[MayStats.columns[1]].tolist()
plt.xticks(x, my_xticks1, rotation='55')

x2 = np.array(JuneStats[JuneStats.columns[0]].tolist())
y2 = np.array(JuneStats[JuneStats.columns[2]].tolist())
my_xticks2 = JuneStats[JuneStats.columns[1]].tolist()
plt.xticks(x, my_xticks2, rotation='55',)

### Plot the data

plt.rc('xtick', labelsize='xx-small')
plt.title('Little Cup Usage')
plt.ylabel('Usage (Percent)')
plt.plot(x,y,label='April', color='green', alpha=.4)
plt.plot(x1,y1,label='May', color='blue', alpha=.4)
plt.plot(x2,y2,label='June', color='red', alpha=.4)
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=.2)
plt.legend()
plt.savefig('90daytest.png', dpi=500)
plt.show()
```

I think I am mislabeling them, but the month of usage isn't stored in the file. I reckon I could add it, but I'd like to not have to go in and edit these files every month. Also, sorry if this is horribly inneficient coding, I have just started learning python less than two weeks ago and this is a little project for me to learn with.

Comment: You've clearly put in some effort, but providing a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) will help in getting good assistance here. In particular, the 'v' part of mcve means that your example data and code should work together to demonstrate the problem you're having -- or at least show where you got on your own.

Comment: Post-script, as I missed the editing window...  Ideally, you would provide code that someone here could simply copy and paste into a python IDE and run (i.e., don't make your readers use `pd.read_clipboard()`). Using `pandas.DataFrame.to_dict()` can help with this.

Comment: ah sorry! I'm new to StackExchange and not up to speed on all the best practices.

Answer (score 1):

I'd divide this into two steps:

1. Gather all the data into a single dataframe in which the rows correspond to the different months, the columns to the different names and the values are the usage %.
2. Plot each column as a different series in a scatter plot.

Step 1:

```
# Create a dictionary associating a file to each month
files = {dt.date(2019, 4, 1): 'april.csv',
        dt.date(2019, 5, 1): 'may.csv'}

# An empty data frame
df = pd.DataFrame()

''' For each file, generate a one entry data frame as follows, and append it to df.
        Month         name1         name2        ...
        2019-1-1      0.5           0.2
''' 
for month, file in files.items():
    data = pd.read_csv(file, usecols=['name', 'usage'], index_col='name')
    data = data.transpose()

    data['month'] = month
    data = data.set_index('month')

    df = df.append(data)
```

Step 2:

```
# New figure
fig = plt.figure()

# Plot one series for each column in df
for name in df.columns:
    plt.scatter(x=df.index, y=df[name], label=name)

# Additional plot formatting code here

plt.show()
```

I hope that helps.